# Cannot read property 'i' of undefined at js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I want to use Google Map API directly in React w/out depending on other ready-coded libraries.

Anyone knows how to fix this errors below, please ... ??

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'i' of undefined
    at js?key=MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap:168
```

Here is google source code for what I want to reproduce. https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/google-maps-simple-store-locator#2

Here is source code in my file /public/index.html

```
<!-- The div to hold the map -->
      <div id="map"></div>  
      <script src="../src/components/StorelocatorComponent.js"></script>
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Here is source code in ../src/components/StorelocatorComponent.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const google = window.google
function initMap() {
    // Create the map.
     const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         zoom: 7,
         center: { lat: 52.632469, lng: -1.689423 },
     });
 
 }
const Storelocator = (props) => {    
    return (
        <div width='100vw' height='100vh'> {initMap} </div>
    );
}
export default Storelocator;
```

Comment: Are you getting any CORS error?

Comment: Hi Rohit. I use Firebase for backend so no CORS usage. I think you refer to the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT", but please no worry about it. It was there because I turned on Adblock.

Comment: I would take a look at @googlemaps/react-wrapper for this usage. The error you are running into is an undefined in your initMap callback. Not sure where that might be from your code. Might also look into useRef...

Comment: Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of what you've done so far in your code?